# How to attach a wheel to a turning axle for a ball machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to make a DIY tennis ball machine. However, I'm not quite sure how to attach the wheels to the steel rods, which will be attached to the motors. In other words, the wheel and the rod should become like one single object, so that rotating the rod will rotate the wheel too. The design is something like the picture below, but the wheels I'll be using can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CVJNLDG). What are your suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at this Q & A : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/25130/10902

Comment: The wheel looks like it's not meant to be driven by its axle so you would need to calculate the torque first, then design a suitable mounting. Or just go overkill and weld a plate to the axle with bolts through the wheel's spokes.

Comment: @user1318499 thanks for the suggestion!